# Limit of general solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let
$$
\begin{cases}
x'(t)=2x(t)-y(t), &   \\
y'(t)=-x(t)+2y(t), &  \\
\end{cases}$$

What are the solutions such that  $\exists \lim_{t\to\infty} \textbf{x}(t)$?

I found the general solution
$x(t)=c_1e^tv_1+c_2e^{3t}v_2$

Where $v_1=\pmatrix{1\\1} $ and $v_2=\pmatrix{1\\-1} $

The answer to my question should be: If $c_2 = 0$ the limit exists and $\lim_{t\to\infty} \textbf{x}(t) =\pmatrix{1\\1}$, otherwise it does not exist. I do not get why the limit exist iff $c_2 = 0$ and also why $c_2 = 0$ implies $\lim_{t\to\infty} \textbf{x}(t) =\pmatrix{1\\1}$. Could you help me with this, please?

**Edit:**
If we were in the discrete case, instead, shouldn't the limit be $\lim_{t\to\infty} \textbf{x}(t) =\pmatrix{c_1\\c_1}$?

Comment: I think your question has a mistake

Comment: The system is antistable, no finite limit for any initial state except zero. It would be the right answer if it were a *discrete* system.

Comment: Ok thank you. In the discrete case, shouldn't the limit be $\lim_{t\to\infty} \textbf{x}(t) =\pmatrix{c_1\\c_1}$? Why it does not depend on c_1?

Answer (score 2):

With the exponential functions given in $$x(t)=c_1e^tv_1+c_2e^{3t}v_2$$ there is no initial values which results in a bounded solution.

More than likely there is a typo in the question which makes both eigenvalues positive.

As you know we need non positive eigenvalues for stability of the system.

Comment: Thank you, but assume that the system were discrete, i.e. a difference equations system. The solution should be $\lim_{t\to\infty} \textbf{x}(t) =\pmatrix{c_1\\c_1}$, provided that c_2=0, am I right?

Comment: Could you help me with this please?